# Laravel queue worker on dokku

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dokku

I have problem with starting Laravel queue worker on latest Dokku.

I am using default heroku php buildpack. There is my procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan queue:work --daemon
```

Worker container is starting, but artisan command is not. No errors in log

If i manually enter worker container and start worker - it starts and works fine.

PS i tried to install shoreman plugin (https://github.com/statianzo/dokku-shoreman.git). Still same result.

Answer (score 1):

remember that your procfile doesn't execute like a .sh file, try with this

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: Command was right, problem was dooku by default scales all container except web to 0. Needed to do `dokku ps:scale app worker=1` manually